# Different MAE values from XGBoost.regressor between a GPU and a CPU notebooks, why?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, gpu, xgboost, kaggle

I'm looking for better XGBoost.regressor options using optune. I have one instance of the laptop running on a local computer (on the processor, my video card does not support machine learning), one on Kaggle code (on a GPU 100). And with the same parameters I get different indicators, they are very different.
Here's the code:

```
def objective(trial, data=data, target=target):

    train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(data, target, test_size=0.15, random_state=SEED)  #, random_state=1234
    param = {
        'objective': 'reg:squarederror',
        'booster': 'gbtree',
        'eval_metric': 'mae',
        # tree_method':'gpu_hist',  # this parameter means using the GPU when training our model to speedup the training process
        'lambda': trial.suggest_float('lambda', 1e-3, 13.0),  # old value 10.0
        'alpha': trial.suggest_float('alpha', 1e-3, 13.0),    # old value 10.0
        'colsample_bytree': trial.suggest_categorical('colsample_bytree', [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]),
        'subsample': trial.suggest_categorical('subsample', [0.3, 0.4,  0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 1.0]),  # added 0.3
        'learning_rate': trial.suggest_categorical('learning_rate', [0.006, 0.008, 0.01, 0.012 ,0.014, 0.016, 0.018, 0.02]),  # added 0.006
        'n_estimators': 50000,  # old 10000
        'max_depth': trial.suggest_categorical('max_depth', [5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]),  # added 19
        'random_state': trial.suggest_categorical('random_state', [SEED]),
        'min_child_weight': trial.suggest_int('min_child_weight', 1, 500),  # old max value=300
        'early_stopping_rounds': 500,  # old 100
    }
    model = xgb.XGBRegressor(**param)

    model.fit(train_x, train_y, eval_set=[(test_x, test_y)], verbose=2000)

    xgb_preds = model.predict(test_x)

    mae = mean_absolute_error(test_y, xgb_preds)

    return mae
```

On the Local CPU i get "Best is trial 48 with value: 1.1957438226176318."
On the Kaggle Code notebook with GPU100 i get - "Best is trial 43 with value: 1.351620287489423."

Why am I getting different results? In Kaggle codes on the notebook I updated the packages using the command:

```
!conda update --all -q -y
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that XGBoost uses different sample methods when using GPU or CPU.

Check `sampling_method` in the [scikit-learn API](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn) documentation.

> sampling_method –
>
> Sampling method. Used only by the GPU version of hist tree method.
> uniform: select random training instances uniformly.
>
> gradient_based select random training instances with higher
> probability when the gradient and hessian are larger. (cf. CatBoost)

Comment: It turns out that he thinks better based on my data?
I never thought that my CPU would be better than GPU :-)

Comment: Is it possible to somehow level the MAE?